# find "corrupt" file, nesting an if inside a find command

Tags: bash, shell, find, quoting

I'm trying to find "corrupt" files inside a directory structure, namely files which the file command would interpret as "data".
Here is the command I've been trying to run, but fails:

```
$ find . -type f -exec if [[ $(file \{} | cut -f2 -d':') == " data" ]] \; then echo " \{}  is CORRUPT" \; else echo " \{} is DATA" \; fi \;
find: paths must precede expression: then
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

I realize I never saw an `if` inside an `-exec` parameter. Is it even possible?

Basically, I'm trying to find files that match that criteria (file would report it as "data", while not identifying a specific file type), and then list them, so that I can analyze before removing.

Comment: `find . -type f -exec file {} \; | grep ': data$'`?

Comment: True, that would get me a list of them, but I am wondering if it's possible to do it all inside the find. Thanks for simplifying it tho

Comment: Are you trying to get the output or trying to build a single command out of curiosity?  If you're just after the output, you've got it, single command, piped command, shouldn't matter?  Although @Cyrus should write that up as an answer obviously.

Comment: Honestly, I will be able to use the output. But if anyone is able to answer the longer question, if it is possible to nest a more complex command inside the -exec, now that would make my day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a shell to interpret those `if/then/else` constructs or run those pipelines (though you don't really need those here):

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    case $(file -b "$file") in
      (data) printf "%s is CORRUPT\n" "$file";;
         (*) printf "%s is DATA\n" "$file";;
    esac
  done' sh {} +
```

(like in your question, it prints "CORRUPT" when `file` says `data`. I'm not sure that's what you meant though).

Whatever you do, don't include `{}` in the shell code like others have suggested! That would be very dangerous (and non-portable btw) as for instance a file called `$(rm -rf "$HOME")` would make you remove your whole home directory.

Comment: Thank you, 
This seems to work as expected, and it somewhat answers my nesting an if question.
Question, thou, as I have very little experience with bash scripting:
How is the for loop working? (how are you looping with `file`, in `for file do`)

Comment: @lolinux The `{}` is replaced by a long list of files by find, which the shell sees as a list of positional arguments. The `for file` just assign each argument in the list to the file variable.

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact answer to your title (nesting an if inside a find), but for all purposes a better solution than inserting a whole shell script inside a find.

Also note that inside a generic `sh` the tests `[[` do not work and the `[` do not match a pattern on the right side of the `=`. Or use a regex match ==~ as I believe you do need. So, you would need a bash shell, which does not make much case if you are already inside a bash shell. In any case, this is faster than starting a new shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    if [[ $(file "$file" | cut -f2 -d':') =~ " data" ]]; then
        printf "%s is CORRUPT\n" "$file"
    else
        printf "%s is DATA\n" "$file"
    fi
done < <(find . -type f -print0)
```

Caveat: I changed your == to a =~ assuming you want to match the `' data'` text in a PNG image (or something similar):

```
$ file TrueTable-1.png| cut -f2 -d':'
PNG image data, 405 x 292, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

Please make a comment if this assumption is not true.

Comment: Thank you,

I realize I haven't been exactly explicit when I said "corrupt" file, I didn't believe it mattered at the time :)

Those files are actually torrent files which I managed to move all from their subdirectories into the central directory with a script that was working on a previous system. Now it behaved differently :)

Thing is that now, when I launched qbittorrent again, it recreated the files, but they are all filled with zeroes (?). What I want to do is identify these zeroed files, remove them and move the originals back in their directories.